# mod_rewrite `Redirect` how?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have 2 urls say `thinkingmonkey.me` and `thinkingmonkey.com` both have ip-address  127.0.0.1 (A.K.A localhost).

I want to redirect any requests to `thinkingmonkey.com` to `thinkingmonkey.me`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /mysite
    ServerName thinkingmonkey.me
    ServerAlias www.thinkingmonkey.me
    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ServerName thinkingmonkey.com
    DocumentRoot /mysite/happ

    Redirect thinkingmonkey.com  http://thinkingmonkey.me/

  #  Redirect / http://thinkingmonkey.me/ #have even tried this

    ServerAlias www.thinkingmonkey.com
    RewriteEngine on
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access `thinkingmonkey.com` the url does not get redirected to `thinkingmonkey.me`. The url in the brower's address bar remains `thinkingmonkey.com`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Redirect /  http://thinkingmonkey.me/
```

Note that this will only redirect the home page. To redirect all pages:

```
RedirectMatch /(.*) http://thinkingmonkey.me/$1
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: `#  Redirect / http://thinkingmonkey.me/ #have even tried this`

Its there in the question.

Comment: Ah so it is. Are you sure you have mod_alias installed (it's usually installed by default) and have you restarted Apache? Also, do you have a NameVirtualHost line somewhere *before* these vhost blocks?

Comment: ya, mod_alias is installed, `NameVirtualHost *:80` is present before `<VirtualHost>` & yes I have restarted httpd.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you also have `NameVirtualHost *:80` specified before your virtual host directives, then try the `Redirect / http://thinkingmonkey.me` again.

Comment: yes it is.. The virtualhosts are working fine. only theredirect is not.

Comment: How do you mean the vhosts are working fine? There's no DocumentRoot directive in the .com vhost block; if it's displaying the content in /mysite, then chances are the vhosts are not working.